# BindingAdapter is not working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, binding

I am trying to add a custom binding to my `TextView`. Please find my code below

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.builders.bindingadaptertest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

`MainViewModel.kt`

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var data =  MutableLiveData<String>()
    init {
        data.value = "This works"
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.builders.bindingadaptertest.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:customBind="@{viewModel.data}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

`BindingAdapters.kt`

```
@BindingAdapter("app:customBind")
fun customBind(view: TextView, data: String?) {
    Log.d("DEBUG_CUSTOM", "Setting custom [$data] listner")
    view.text = data
}
```

Doubt: When I run this project, The log cat shows the data passing to `customBind` is `null`.

```
2020-11-30 09:37:33.351 4682-4682/com.builders.bindingadaptertest D/DEBUG_CUSTOM: Setting custom [null] listner
```

Can anyone help me to get the correct data from ViewModel into the binding adapter?

Answer (score 2):

It's null, because in your `databinding` `viewModel` is not set.

You forgot to add `binding.viewModel = model`

Also, some possible suggestions:

1. No need to leave the `LiveData` reference mutable, just use `val`
2. I'd prefer an extension function for the binding adapter: `fun TextView.customBind(data: String?)`
3. You should set a `lifecycleOwner` on your `binding`, otherwise your `activity` may keep an indirect reference on your `vm`, which will cause leaks on orientation changes